# Product pages generate 500 Server Error but store is otherwise fine

Tags: magento-1.8

I have a situation where Magento seems to work generally, but throws 500 Internal Server Errors on product pages only.

I have a working Magento (1.8 CE) store that needs to be copied to a second server.  I started with a clean server build, then copied the working Magento installation via rsync (preserving permissions).  The servers share a database, Redis cache, and /var and /media directories.

The secondary installation almost works - I can browse store categories, search for products, log into the admin area, etc., however single product pages don't load correctly.  Firebug shows the main request for the product is generating a 500 Internal Server Error.  The page renders correct navigation, product images, SKU and pricing, but stops at the description and doesn't render the footer.

The new server passes the Magento server readiness check script.  From what I can tell, the permissions are identical to the working server and match the recommended Magento permissions. Since both servers share a database, all the internal settings are the same.  Magento logging is on, and I have both "ini_set('log_errors', 1)" and "error_reporting(E_ALL)" in index.php, but there is no more detail in any of the logs.

Not sure where to go from here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I assume your error log is writable by the user executing the php.)

It's probably not related to the problem, but I'd never share a `var/` directory. Just stick sessions into Redis. If you serve content from `var/` like exports, then just share that.

From the source you should be able to tell what part in the template it's failing on. Please update your answer with the template name lines of code that should be run at the point of failure. (If it's the add to cart button, then sessions may actually be relevant if the same session is accessed by both servers at the same time, but if it's always reproducible this seems unlikely).

One thing to check is output of `php -m` on both servers. Common mistake is to forget a module, like an Ioncube loader.

Comment: Brilliant!  As soon as you said Ioncube I knew that was it; I forgot to install it on the second server.  Now it works properly!  Thanks for shining a light on that.